# javascript: get element's Y position from top of the browser's display area

Tags: javascript, position

I need to get an element (whatever it is) and be able to print its absolute Y position. In order to calculate the gap between the top of the object and the top of the whole document. How to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code;

```
const offsets = document.getElementById('elementId').getBoundingClientRect();
const topY = offsets.top;
const bottomY  = offsets.bottom;
```

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect